# update Web/Services References not working

Tags: c#, wcf

I am trying to update my Web/Services References from VS and going on App_WebReferences and right-click go to Update Web/Services References.    No files are open in my Visual Studio. I open it by using File/Open Web Site and the name of the web sites.

Here is the error I got.  Failed to update Service Reference "CarServiceReference.Reference." Error: Unable to connect to the configured development Web Server.   Failed to register URL

"http://:...." for site "CarDealer" application "/". Error description: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

Any idea on how to get over this error ?
Thanks for any propose solution

Comment: Have you tried closing Visual Studio and re-opening? Seems like the web development server is running (or hung) and can't accessed.

Comment: one step done !!!  I was able to perform the Update Web/Services.

Comment: anytime when we get an error from visual studio that "the process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process", try to stop the running program. if it's not in the status bar, try to kill the process in task manager.

Answer (score 1):

Like Sixto Saez said, I shut down Visual Studio and re-open it, choose my Web Solution and then I was able to Update the Web/Services.  Thanks